# К сожалению, нам не удалось найти файл по факту он там есть

Tags: vba, visual-basic

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Программа в excel при нажатии загрузить в привод Бондаря выдает эту ошибку.]

```
Private Sub Open_xml(Path, FileName, Sheet, Cell As String)
Dim strTargetFile As String
Dim wb
strTargetFile = Path & "\" & FileName
Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(FileName:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range(Cell)
wb.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сказал же, проверьте расширение. Есть файл "XDSD.TQBR.AGRO_Settings.tmp" и "XDSD.TQBR.AGRO_Settings.xml", но нет файла "XDSD.TQBR.AGRO_Settings".

В Проводнике Windows нужно включить отображение расширений.

Или в строке адреса в этой папке напечатать "cmd". Откроется окно командной строки. Дать команду "dir". Выведется список файлов с расширениями.

[image: Проводник Windows]

Comment: как проверить это расширение и где

Comment: См. первоначальный вопрос

Comment: На картинке красным выделено folder options там надо будет галочку поставить или убрать

Comment: Да, но это не решает проблему, а просто даёт убедиться, что файла, который пытается открыть программа, в папке нет. А решение я добавил в ответ на первоначальный вопрос.

Comment: Я в проводнике включил  отображение расширений вроде всё заработало ошибок не выдаёт, завтро проверю в приводе Бондаря большое спасибо.

Comment: Тогда можно отметить ответ как принятый и полезный :-) Спасибо, как говорится, в карман не положишь...